# Issue passing NSDate in WCSession Payload

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

Since WCSession only allows property list types I am creating a property list dictionary for data I am parsing from my object.

The documentation states that it should be supporting NSDate, NSNumber, NSString...etc

However, probably 90% of the time I get this error upon attempting to pass the NSDate.

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7010 "Payload contains unsupported type."
```

My actual payload is an array of dictonarys containing NSString types, NSDate types and NSNumber types.

My debugging points to the issue being specifically NSDate. Any ideas what is going on here? Is NSDate supported for WCSession payloads?

Comment: I don't know anything about `WCSession` but if `NSDate` isn't working, pass the date as an `NSNumber` using the date's `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it says it supports NSDate, NSNumber, etc? Where I looked it all said "A dictionary of property list values" or "property list object types"

Comment: Apple defines property list types as [such](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might convert to a string and back using

```
import Foundation

let UtcDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let utcDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    utcDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
    utcDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
    utcDateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    utcDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
    return utcDateFormatter
}()
```